# Why there is a size difference between calling a parameterized array and calling an array using pointer and new?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, integer, sizeof

Actually I've seen that, when I try to define an array it's better to allocate the size after defining the index size. So, to define the size that way I wrote this...

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int *array,size;
    cout<<"The size of the array pointer: "<<sizeof(array)<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the size of your array: ";
    cin>>size;
    array=new int[size];
    cout<<"The size of the array pointer: "<<sizeof(array)<<endl;
//  During the compilation the above line of code is ignored & won't shown in the Console.
    cout<<"Enter elements:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cin>>array[i];
    }
    cout<<"Your array: ";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl<<"The size of the array pointer: "<<sizeof(array)<<endl;
}
```

But, from the beginning the size of the array shows 8 Bytes, while each integer takes 4 bytes of memory. I've no problem while storing an array of any size. It works as same as a parameterized array. But, my question is why it took only 8 bytes of memory?

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(array)`  is the size of the pointer, not an `int` or your array.

In general, use `std::vector<int>` instead.

And not use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't ell you the size of an array pointed by the pointer, just how much space is used by the pointer.